# Replace Subject fields on Lightning Email Template

Tags: email, email-template, string, replace

I'm having problems with replace() operations of text that I have in Subject of my Email Template.

Subject is like: A - B - C

My code is:

```
    EmailTemplate eTemplate = newEmail.searchForEmailTemplate('MyTemplate');
                eTemplate.Subject.replace('A', 'Test1: ' + String.valueOf(Account.Sending__c) + ' ');
                eTemplate.Subject.replace('B', 'Test2: ' + String.valueOf(Account.Stat__c) + ' ');
                eTemplate.Subject.replace('C', 'Test3: ' + String.valueOf(Account.GetMethods__c) + ' ');

System.debug('eTemplate.Subject --> ' + eTemplate.Subject);
```

But it does not work. Debug prints: **A - B - C**, so, Subject did not change.

Answer (score 0):

The replace method on String class doesn't modify the String on which is being Called. Instead it would return a new string with the modifications.

Please read more about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

[image]

Comment: Ostac -- community etiquette is to not solicit acceptance of the answer - see https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed; we're different than SFDC Developers Forum in this respect